# Javascript, Protoype Objects, jQuery, and Timers

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I thought I had fixed this on Friday through a type correction, but I did not :(

I have been beating my head trying to find a solution to this problem (if there is one to be had). Maybe I'm not searching for the right thing, but I just can't find a solution to this one...

**The Setup:**

```
$.myPlugin = function(element, options){
    this.myElement = $(element);
    this.myElement.data('rotator', '');
    this.myElement.data('settings', $.extend({}, $.myPlugin.defaultOptions, options));
    this.mainFunction(this.myElement);
};

$.myPlugin.defaultOptions = { // yadda yadda };


$.myPlugin.prototype = {
    mainFunction : function(myself){
        // establish initial parameters
        var TEST = Math.rand();

        // do a bunch of stuff
        $(myButton).live('click', function(){               
            alert(TEST) //<---FOR TESTING PURPOSES

            // do other things
            myself.data('rotator', setTimeout(function(){               
                // click button after x period
                myButton.click();   
            }, x ));    
        });
    },

    destroy : function(){
        myself = $(this);
        myself.myElement.removeData('settings');
        clearTimeout(myself.data('rotator'));
    }
};

$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) { 
    // parse options
    this.each(function(){
        var instance = $(this).data('myPlugin');

        // blah blah blah ... on create
        $(this).data('myPlugin', new $.myPlugin(this, args));

        // blah blah blah ... on destroy
        instance['destroy'].apply(this);
        $(this).data('ddGallery', null);
    };
    return this;
};
```

**The Desired Function:**

In my logic, I want to create an object on an element. The plugin then stores the contents of the element in a variable, and puts new content in it. There is an auto-timed event that is invoked on click, with a .live() click listener; the click event resets the timer resulting in a loop (as opposed to using setInterval). On destroy, I replace the stored original html contents and *want to* kill the object. So far, this all works. I want to then be able to recreate the object on the element (perhaps passing in different settings).

***This is where it all goes wrong:***

When I recreate the object on the same element after destruction, the original timer continues to run. **I can't get rid of the stinkin' timer, and I'm about to rip my hair out!**

To test, I set a random number on initialization, and alert that number on click. Initially, I might get an alert of, for example, "0.1234". I can then destroy the object (I'm just using a listener on a form button to create and destroy). The element will return to it's initial state, and happily sit indefinitely. However, as soon as I run the plugin on the element again, the original "0.12345" alert pops up immediately with no delay (and all animations fire). That is followed by another *new* popup, e.g., "0.5678". Now BOTH timers continue to fire on the element, wreaking havoc.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that your real code? `clearTimeout(myself.data('rotator');` is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Not real code, just there to give gist (fixed above)

Comment: Yeah... whoops again, fixed again ... supposed to be $.extend()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't unbinding the original click event on the button in your destroy method.  You need to add a call like:

```
   myself.die('click');
```

in your destroy method.  The reason you are seeing the original random number alerted on the future click is because you bound a closure to the click event the first time through.  You kill the timer but don't unbind the click handler.

The next time you click the button you bind a new click handler; now you have TWO click handlers, each of which is a closure that remembers the random number that was generated at the time it was created.  Now a single timer fires repeatedly clicking the element and each time it clicks it triggers both click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using jQuery's data function, I have a feeling that the creation of new jQuery objects in your code is hurting your ability to reference the timer. Try

```
 this.rotator = setTimeout(...
```

vs

```
 $(this).data('rotator', setTimeout(...
```

the clear would look like this:

```
clearTimeout(this.rotator);
```

Comment: I tried it both ways, and it didn't make any difference. If I alert the rotator variable inside the destroy function, it is returning the id, but it just won't clear it. ... hmmm... maybe if I make a "setMyTimer" function and put it outside of prototype? (or am I misunderstanding inheritance? I'm fairly new to OOP)